Generalized Uniform Continuity?
I know that if $X$ is compact metric space then a continuous map $F:X\rightarrow Y$ is uniformly continuous and if $X$ not compact then it is not always true. But I was wonder if something for more general holds like:
If $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces and $F:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous and $C\subseteq X$ is closed, does it follow that for every continuous $\epsilon:X\rightarrow (0,\infty)$, there exists a continuous $\delta:C\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ sucht that if $c\in C$ and $d(x,c)<\delta(c)$ then $d(F(x),F(c))<\epsilon(c)$?

Did you really mean $\epsilon(x)$? Or did you mean $\epsilon(c)$? Besides, every metric space $X$ is a closed subspace of itself. Therefore, you gain nothing by adding that closed subset $C$.

@JoséCarlosSantos $\epsilon(c)$.. sorry!

This was first shown by Ali Enayat,

[MR1745893][1] (2000m:54014). Enayat, Ali. [$\delta$ as a continuous function of $x$ and $\epsilon$][2]. Amer. Math. Monthly 107 (2000), no. 2, 151–155.


but if $X$ is not compact, $F$ can still be uniformly continuous.

@AngaeMT yes obviously, edited

$\delta(c) = \min(1, \sup {s | \forall x \in B_s(c): d(F(x), F(c)) < \epsilon(c)})$ satisfies the condition and is continuous, as $|\delta(x) - \delta(y)| \leq d(x, y)$.

@mihaild what if the supremum is empty?

@monoidaltransform assuming you mean "set under supremum" - it's not possible, as $\epsilon(x) > 0$ and $F$ is continuous.

@mihaild because $\epsilon>0$ and $F$ is continuous, ${s: $\forall x\in B_{s}(c):$, $d(F(x),F(c))<\epsilon(c)$ }$  is non-empty?

Yes. Let $g(x) = d(F(x), F(c))$. $g$ is contionuous, thus $g^{-1}((-1, \epsilon))$ is open and contains $c$, so it also contains some open ball with center in $c$, and radius os this ball is in this set.
